# DNS server with two virtual NICs

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I configured a DNS server in my CentOS virtual machine which was connect to vmnet2(host only)IP 192.168.0.0/24. and It work perfectly. Then I set another adapter and set it to NAT for take internet connectivity. Then I tried nslookup command and it tries to resolve it using isp dns server. My requirment is first it should try to resolve using local dns and if not it should forward to isp side my nat iprange is 192.168.205.0/24.

my resolv.conf

```
# Generated by NetworkManager 
#search server
search sithila.server
nameserver 192.168.0.10
[ other commented material deleted ]
```

nslookup output with one network card (vmnet2)

```
[sithila@sithila ~]$ nslookup www.sithila.server
Server:     192.168.0.10
Address:    192.168.0.10#53

Name:   www.sithila.server
Address: 192.168.0.10
```

nslookup output with two network cards (vmnet2 and NAT)

```
[sithila@sithila ~]$ nslookup www.sithila.server
Server:     192.168.205.2
Address:    192.168.205.2#53

** server can't find www.sithila.server: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and paste it into your question.

Comment: Sorry, I should also have added, what's the IP address of this virtual server?

Comment: it was static ip 192.168.0.10/24 in eth0 which is connected to vmnet2

Comment: That's weird.  How do you know that `nslookup` is trying to resolve off the ISP's server?  If you have some output to paste into your question, that would be good, too.

Comment: I guessed it because resolving server ip shows ip in NAT pool

Comment: That output's grand, can you confirm that `resolv.conf` is as you've shown **even in that second case, when you're getting resolution from 192.168.205.2**?  I only ask because I can't imagine where else the server's getting that address, as a resolution choice.

Comment: Thanx resolv.conf have changed I reconfigured it. now it take local server, Is there possible way to add isp side dns server as secondary if i type nslookup www.google.com it should resolve

Comment: smk, forgive me for mentioning this, but local etiquette is that when you're happy with an answer to your question, you accept it by clicking the "tick" outline next to it, which drives the SF reputation system both for you and the author of the answer.  My apologies if you already knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as per the comments thread above we've now nailed down that your server was asking the wrong server because the wrong server was listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  That's good, and it should provide a handy object lesson for you, that **when you're testing something, such as the contents of a file, to see if it might be causing a problem, you should perform the test when the problem is happening**!

As for your second question, I do not think there is any way to do that via `resolv.conf`.  Instead, you should configure your local nameserver to use your upstream nameserver(s) as forwarders; the entry in `named.conf` would look something like

```
zone "." {
        type forward ;
        forwarders {
                192.168.205.2 ;
        } ;
} ;
```

That tells your local name server to kick any questions it can't answer across the wall to your upstream server; you can then leave just your local nameserver listed in `resolv.conf`, and it should deal with all queries accordingly.